# JSON Multiple urls with the headers

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have multiple urls in $.ajax https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/ and https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + item,
headers:{
  'Client-ID': 'k7uj51l1cteh0sbhwplk4hqq6c7bqo'},
success: function(data){
  console.log(data);
},
error: function(data){
alert("doesn't work")
},
});
```

but I also need to have headers with 'Client-ID'. I was trying with this:

```
 $.getJSON(channel, function(e){
   $.getJSON(stream,function(f){
  });   
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to get two ajax request and get data in each one.

Comment: what are your `channel` and `string` object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it seems you forgot to add one more header `"accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json"`**

---

The complete working code example

```js
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/44322889",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "client-id": "k7uj51l1cteh0sbhwplk4hqq6c7bqo",
    "accept": "application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

checkout this code

Comment: This is really not helpfull without explanation, and doesn't look related to OPs issue. You might want to read [answer] to see what is expected from a good answer, and then [edit] your post accordingly